# How can I supress the Exceptions generated by the ZK framework?

Tags: java, exception, zk

ZK generates its own exceptions like Numberformat Exception for a blank intbox etc. I want to show my own custom error page in such cases not the popup generated by ZK implicitly. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a [error page](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Error_Handling) in `zk.xml` for a specified Exception class.